# How many strings (alphanumerical) of length 7 have exactly one number?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

My reasoning seems to fail here : I say there's  $26^6\times 10$*, but my answer is wrong and I don't understand why.

EDIT 1 : Thanks to Carl I realise I need to use a combination because I'm not counting differently ordered strings as being different. So why isn't *$26^6\times {10 \choose 1}$ the right answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pick

- the first letter
- the second letter
- the third letter
- the fourth letter
- the fifth letter
- the sixth letter
- the one and only digit
- the position of the one and only digit

Comment: Okay so discretizing (as it were) the tasks like that and using the product rule I should get $26^6 \times 10 \times {7 \choose 1}$

Answer (score 1):

The quantity $26^6\cdot 10$ tells you a) how to pick the $6$ letters in order, and b) how to pick the one digit, but it doesn't tell you where the digit goes in the string. For example, you're not classifying the strings "8aabaea" and "aa8baea" as different. What do you need to change?

Comment: I should take order into account, so use combination instead of permutation

Comment: @Quarantiner Not really -- permutation takes order into account, while combination doesn't. The particular component of order you're not taking into account is where the number occurs within the string.

Comment: Oh yes okay so I shouldn't take into account where the number occurs... So should the answer be $26^6\times {10\choose 1}$ (6 letters and one number chosen out of 10) ? I don't really get what I'm not understanding...

Comment: @Quarantiner Where is the numerical digit going to go?  You have to apply the scalar of $7$ to your answer to reflect that the numerical digit can be placed in any one of 7 slots.  Other than that oversight, your intuition is good.